# ¿Es posible convertir un Object result en un Arreglo en C#?

Tags: c#, array, stored-procedure, object

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
public List<AnfitrionDto> Seleccionar()
        {
            List<AnfitrionDto> ret = new List<AnfitrionDto>();
            VisitantesEntities db = new VisitantesEntities();            
            Anfitrion[] registros = db.SpAnfitrionConsultar();         
            foreach (var registro in registros)
            {
                ret.Add(AnfitrionAdaptador.ConvertirADto(registro));
            }
        return ret;
    }
```

En el cual hago el llamado de un SP con nombre SpAnfitrionConsultar, pero me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible convertir un Object result en un Arreglo en C#?
Me parece que ese es el problema que tengo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar .ToArray();

```
public List<AnfitrionDto> Seleccionar()
        {
            List<AnfitrionDto> ret = new List<AnfitrionDto>();
            VisitantesEntities db = new VisitantesEntities();            
            Anfitrion[] registros = db.SpAnfitrionConsultar().ToArray();         
            foreach (var registro in registros)
            {
                ret.Add(AnfitrionAdaptador.ConvertirADto(registro));
            }
        return ret;
    }
```

De todos modos, por que no utilizas `List<T>` en lugar de array?

```
public List<AnfitrionDto> Seleccionar()
        {
            List<AnfitrionDto> ret = new List<AnfitrionDto>();
            VisitantesEntities db = new VisitantesEntities();            
            var registros = db.SpAnfitrionConsultar().ToList();
            foreach (var registro in registros)
            {
                ret.Add(AnfitrionAdaptador.ConvertirADto(registro));
            }
        return ret;
    }
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Los tipos que quieres convertir parecen ser muy diferentes, quizas debas usar automapper o quizas linq, porque mas alla que sea un `ObjectResult` a un array, los tipos no coinciden, tienes que mapear el tipo `SpAnfitrionConsultar_Result` a `AnfitrionDto` es aqui donde interviene linq

```
public List<AnfitrionDto> Seleccionar()
{
    List<AnfitrionDto> ret = null;
    using(VisitantesEntities db = new VisitantesEntities())
    {    
        var registros = db.SpAnfitrionConsultar();  

        ret = registros.Select(item => new AnfitrionDto()
        {
            prop1 = item.prop1,
            prop2 = item.prop2,
            //resto
        })
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

en este caso en el `Select` de `linq` deberias mapear las propiedades correctas de cada entidad

Ademas recomendaria le des una mirada al articulo

[Call Stored Procedure From Entity Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/call-store-procedure-from-entity-framework/)

si revisa la imagen del `step 3` veras que puedes indicar el tipo que retorna la ejecucion del procedure